# Google Cloud Storage Repository Plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a K8 cluster on GCP running elasticsearch. Now I need to create a backup.

I've installed the GCS-plugin on my pods in stateful-set and tried setting it up with the following documentation: 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/plugins/repository-gcs.asciidoc

When I try to configure a repository to use credentials stored in keystore I get the following response back:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "repository_exception",
                "reason": "[my_backup] repository type [gcs] does not exist"
            }
        ],
        "type": "repository_exception",
        "reason": "[my_backup] repository type [gcs] does not exist"
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

Any lead would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that I can't install the plugin on the nodes, so I’ve installed it on the pods instead. And that the installation is not persistent after I restart the pods. So to make the installation persist on K8 I needed to build a custom image that installs the plugin. A bit tricky, but the plugin seems to be intended for GCE. So I decided to move from K8 to a managed instance group on GCE instead.